# C compiler error: cannot convert to a pointer type

Tags: c

I'm trying to use the FreeType library together with libpng to output a PNG image of a glyph. I can create a raster bitmap of the glyph and I can create a valid PNG file, but I can't seem to put the two together. The problem comes from this line near the end:

```
png_bytep image = (png_bytep) slot->bitmap;
```

It seems that I can't simply cast the FreeType bitmap to a `png_bytep` and pass it to pnglib (this was wishful thinking). I get the following error:

```
/home/david/Desktop/png.c: In function ‘main’:
/home/david/Desktop/png.c:47:2: error: cannot convert to a pointer type
```

However, I'm not sure how to proceed from here. But Here's the full block of code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <png.h>

#include <ft2build.h>
#include FT_FREETYPE_H

main() {

    // Declare FreeType variables
    FT_Library library;
    FT_Face face;
    FT_GlyphSlot slot = face->glyph;
    FT_UInt glyph_index;
    int pen_x, pen_y, n;
    char* file = "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeMono.ttf";

    // Declare PNG variables
    png_uint_32 width = 100;
    png_uint_32 height = 100;
    int bit_depth = 16;
    int color_type = PNG_COLOR_TYPE_GRAY;
    char* file_name = "/home/david/Desktop/out.png";
    png_structp png_ptr;
    png_infop info_ptr;

    // Render font
    FT_New_Face(library, file, 0, &face);
    FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes(face, 0, 16);
    glyph_index = 30;
    FT_Load_Glyph(face, glyph_index, FT_LOAD_DEFAULT);
    FT_Render_Glyph(face->glyph, FT_RENDER_MODE_NORMAL);

    // Create a PNG file
    FILE *fp = fopen(file_name, "wb");

    // Create the PNG in memory
    png_ptr = png_create_write_struct(PNG_LIBPNG_VER_STRING, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    info_ptr = png_create_info_struct(png_ptr);
    png_init_io(png_ptr, fp);

    // Write the header
    png_set_IHDR(png_ptr, info_ptr, width, height, bit_depth, color_type, PNG_INTERLACE_NONE, PNG_COMPRESSION_TYPE_BASE, PNG_FILTER_TYPE_BASE);
    png_write_info(png_ptr, info_ptr);

    // Write image data
    png_bytep image = (png_bytep) slot->bitmap;
    png_write_image(png_ptr, &image);

    // End write
    png_write_end(png_ptr, NULL);

    fclose(fp);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void png_write_image(png_structp png_ptr, png_bytepp image);
typedef png_byte        FAR * FAR * png_bytepp;
typedef unsigned char png_byte;
```

So png_write_image is looking for a input of type `unsigned char far * far *`.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Far_pointer if you are interested in what the far means.

Now if you look at your FT_GlyphSlot type you will find:

```
typedef struct  FT_GlyphSlotRec_
  {
...
FT_Bitmap         bitmap;
...
}

typedef struct  FT_Bitmap_
{
  int             rows;
  int             width;
  int             pitch;
  unsigned char*  buffer;
  short           num_grays;
  char            pixel_mode;
  char            palette_mode;
  void*           palette;
} FT_Bitmap;
```

So to get the right type you would need `&slot->bitmap.buffer`.

No cast should be necessary.

Comment: Thanks! Same answer as Tar but a little more in-depth. Both great answers though! And still trying to figure out the segfault happening in the 'Render font' section. Any ideas? :-)

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you should pass `&image` instead of image.

Comment: Thanks. This cleared up some of the errors, but the main error is the same. I'll update the post.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want slot->bitmap.buffer instead of slot->bitmap

slot->bitmap is an FT_Bitmap, a struct type, that also contains the bitmaps width, etc.

Comment: Ah, that worked. It compiled! Now there's a segfault to deal with, but I guess that may be a different question :-). Thanks!

Comment: You need to call `FT_Init_FreeType(&library)` before using freetype. `FT_GlyphSlot slot = face->glyph;` should be below the function call that creates the face. The next problems are somewhere in your use of libpng.

Comment: Genius. Right again. Now the segfault happens lower down in the 'Render font' code. I don't suppose you have any more suggestions? ;-)

Comment: You tell libpng that the bitmap is 100x100, freetype is highly unlikely to provide that, isn't it?

Comment: Indeed, the "FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes" call is causing the segfault. Investigating now...